# How do you change the "Check ID" of an "Uptime Check" in Google "Monitoring"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

-Is there anyway to edit the "Check ID" after creating the "Uptime Check"? Here's an example screenshot for what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried in my own project, but after further investigation I found the following:

As per [UptimeCheckConfig](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.uptimeCheckConfigs#resource:-uptimecheckconfig) **"Check ID"** it's auto-assigned by GCP when the check is created, and **can't** be modified ".

This field should be omitted when creating the Uptime check configuration; on create, the resource name is assigned by the server and included in the response"

`name`:

```
 projects/[PROJECT_ID_OR_NUMBER]/uptimeCheckConfigs/[UPTIME_CHECK_ID]
```